# Is it possible to create an action hook using do_action() within add_action()?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions, callbacks

Is it possible to create a new action hook like `do_action('my-hook-name');` inside a call to `add_action();`?

I'm aware this code doesn't work, but I was thinking something along the lines of...
`add_action('init', do_action('my-hook-name'));`

or

Is the only way to actually add a callback function to `init`, then inside my callback function create my hook?

```
add_action('init', 'my_callback');
function my_callback(){
    do_action('my-hook-name');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What's the use-case, though? Why not just fire on the existing action you hook into?

Comment: Creating a plugin which hooks into theme hooks. Looking to provide plugin hooks to the theme hooks. It's not a big deal to actually create a callback, just thought it would be nice to have shorter code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work for you? I mean, the second parameter is supposed to be a callback (just asking, for I get an error)

Comment: @IvanHanák No, `add_action('init', do_action('my-hook-name'));` Does not work. I was asking if is possible to do something similar to that which actually works.

Comment: In such a case, anonymous function should do the magic `add_action('init', (function(){do_action('i_am_a_hook');}));`

Comment: And anonymous functions in hook calls are not user- or child-theme friendly.

Comment: @ChipBennett If you can think of a more elegant way of handling this, please do share. Otherwise, I have added an answer which suggests using anonymous functions to handle creating hooks using `do_action()` on a call to `add_action()`. I have also noted to be cautious of using anonymous functions with hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an answer based upon responses via comments on original question of: [Is it possible to create an action hook using do_action() within add_action()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123184/is-it-possible-to-create-an-action-hook-using-do-action-within-add-action)

Yes it is possible to create an action hook using `do_action()` on a call to `add_action()`.

For clarification, the following code does **NOT** work:

`add_action('init', do_action('my-hook-name'));`

As stated by [`@IvanHanák`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/40545/ivan-hanak) in the comments to the original question asked; It is possible to create an action hook using `do_action()` on a call to `add_action()` by using [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

An example of creating an action hook using `do_action()` on a call to `add_action()` using anonymous functions:

`add_action('some-existing-hook-name', function(){do_action('my-new-hook-name');});`

However, it should be noted that using anonymous functions can make it difficult to debug or remove hooks.