# Conditional action hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I wanted to add the action hook below only if we are not in a specific product ID. So i tried something like this in my functions.php

```
global $product;
$productId = $product->get_id();
if ($productId != 1345){
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
```

But, it's impossible to call the $product variable out of a function.

So i tried to do this

```
function woocommerce_add_new_add_to_cart(){
global $product;
$productId = $product->get_id();
if ($productId != 1345){
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_add_new_add_to_cart', 10);
```

And it didn't work as well.

So then i found this post : [Is it possible to create an action hook using do_action() within add_action()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123184/is-it-possible-to-create-an-action-hook-using-do-action-within-add-action)

And i tried this

```
function woocommerce_add_new_add_to_cart(){
    global $product;
    $productId = $product->get_id();

    if ($productId != 1345){
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function(){do_action('woocommerce_add_new_add_to_cart');});
```

And it doesn't work as well. What's wrong ? How can i do this ? Any idea ? :/

Thanks

Comment: When in the product phase do you want to add the function when an item is added to the cart? Or when they go to the product page? What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: while there might be a non WC specific solution, the only valid answer right now is "do not use globals in context in which you are not 1000% sure they are properly set" which is not a great answer, but the best that can be given without diving into WC internals, therefor at its current form it is off topic. If you think you can rewrite it to not be so WC specific, go for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce adds the action hook at priority order 30.

`add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);`

So, You may have done

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);
```

to remove the action from the hook. To remove an action the priority must match the priority with with the function was originally added.

Now you can do

```
function add_cart_button(){
  global $product;
  $id = $product->get_id();
  if($id != 1345 ):
  add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30); // You should note this should trigger later tested at 20, 30, 35 working
  endif;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','add_cart_button'); // This triggers at 10 by default
```

To add the button again.

You should check the order of execution of functions in a hook.